# Modify only the text layer under a searchable Pdf

Tags: java, text, itext, pdfbox, searchable

I have a pdf on which we conduct OCR and get the resultant PDf.
This PDF is in  a searchable format althought the text layer in this pdf has some erroneous data due to the OCR.
I want to modify only the text layer within this new Pdf without changing the pdf image itself.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: First of all, the format PDF does not know "text layers". Yes, some Adobe products do use that term but not for something intrinsic in the actual PDF but merely in their way to manipulate them. That being said, changing the text in a PDF in general is non trivial. For example the fonts used may contain only glyphs for the currently present text on the page, so your desired replacement probably cannot be represented using that font and you have to add an additional font to the page and switch fonts in your replacement. For other issues read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655298/1729265).

Comment: Probably in case of your PDFs there aren't many hindrances and editing is possible. Please share representative examples to analyse and find out which hindrances there are.

Comment: find a good approach?