# How to save a string into PDF in PDFBox?

Tags: java, string, pdf, replace, pdfbox

I'm currently working with PDFBox to create a PDF where the necessary spots are filled with the correct information. I have my string in the project, but for some reason, I cannot put that string into a pdf file with the `doc.save();` functionality.

Is there any way to do such things, or should I approach this problem with a different manner?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "testPDF.pdf";
        
        try{
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf"));
            String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);

            String name = text.replace("nameReplace", "Example Ethan");
            
            doc.save(fileName);
            doc.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The text stripper merely gives you an independent string representing the text PDFBox could recognized. You cannot change the PDF by manipulating that string (and strictly speaking you don't even manipulate that string but create a new, again independent string...).

Comment: Then how should I approach this problem, if the text stripper is not the thing I'm looking for?

Comment: First of all, PDF is not designed for replacing text pieces in a search and replace manner, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655298/1729265). Thus, you should reconsider the architecture of your task. Alternatives might be using pdfs with form fields to fill in, or doing search and replace in another, more suitable format and only thereafter exporting to pdf.

Comment: If you really cannot avoid having to search and replace text in pdfs, then there are two cases: 1. Your pdf is internally built in a very simple way, avoiding all the pitfalls mentioned in the answer referred to above. In this case you can do text replacement in content streams. 2. Otherwise you'll essentially have to apply redaction to the pdf to remove the text to replace and add new text there.

Comment: In your opinion, this text stripper option should be used for a pdf with fill forms, or is there another way to do it? I checked out the API documentation a few times, but I couldn't find anything related to my issue.

Comment: The text stripper is for text extraction. If you extend it a bit, for extraction of text with position or with some style information. It is not for text changing. For form field fill-ins look for `PDAcroForm` use in the API and the examples.

Answer (score 0):

**If I understand correctly, you want to edit a sentence in the PDF**

> ```
>    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
> ```

```
              stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                
              String text = stripper.getText(doc);
              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bluca\\b");
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
                

     matcher.find();
                  String group = matcher.group();
                  int start = matcher.start();
                  int end = matcher.end();
        String hj=  matcher.    replaceFirst("Carlone");
              System.out.println(group + " " + start + " " + end+hj);
```

Comment: The OP wanted to eventually have a PDF with the text replaced, not only is extracted text.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "testPDF.pdf";
        
        try {
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf"));
            String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);

            // Assuming the text you want to replace is on the first page
            PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
            
            if (text.contains("nameReplace")) {
                // Remove the content of the first page
                page.setContents(null);
                
                try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true)) {
                    // Here you would ideally re-add all the previous content (this example won't cover that)
                    
                    // Add replaced text (for simplicity, this example assumes the text fits in the given position)
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
                    contentStream.showText(text.replace("nameReplace", "Example Ethan"));
                    contentStream.endText();
                }
            }

            doc.save(fileName);
            doc.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Here you would ideally re-add all the previous content (this example won't cover that)"* - but adding the previous content (except the `nameReplace` occurrence) in general is the only non-trivial part of your approach...